# Inserting Different Value IN a Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

Well I'm Creating a Table Based on Result Set Of Databases On Server which contain Multiple Databases.
       My table will Create a list of column which contain Database_Name

FOR EG:

```
 DECLARE @strt INT,@End INT,@Database NVARCHAR(20), @ColumnDeclaration  VARCHAR(2000),@SqlSelect NVARCHAR(MAX),@column_Name NVARCHAR(255)

    SELECT * INTO #T FROM SYS.DATABASES 
     ORDER BY NAME

        SELECT @ColumnDeclaration=STUFF(( SELECT ', ' + Name + ' NVARCHAR(255)'
                                                    FROM #T
                                                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(max)'), 1, 1, '')


        SET @SqlSelect=' CREATE TABLE Temp_Comp (' + @ColumnDeclaration + ');'
                PRINT @SqlSelect
                EXEC (@SqlSelect)

SELECT * FROM Temp_Comp
```

Comment: I wan't Insert the Data INTO Temp_Comp Table a specific Value from the database whose Name will be in Temp_comp Table

Answer (score 0):

> I wan't Insert the Data INTO Temp_Comp Table a specific Value from
>   the database whose Name will be in Temp_comp Table

Not sure what are you trying to achieve, but I assume that you want something like:

```
DECLARE @strt INT,@End INT,@Database NVARCHAR(20), @ColumnDeclaration  NVARCHAR(MAX),@SqlSelect NVARCHAR(MAX),@column_Name NVARCHAR(255)

SELECT * INTO #T 
FROM SYS.DATABASES 
ORDER BY NAME;

 SELECT @ColumnDeclaration=STUFF(( SELECT ', ' + QUOTENAME(Name) + ' NVARCHAR(255)'
                                                    FROM #T
                                                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(max)'), 1, 1, '');


SET @SqlSelect=' CREATE TABLE Temp_Comp (col_desc NVARCHAR(200), ' + @ColumnDeclaration + ');';
SELECT @SqlSelect;
EXEC (@SqlSelect);


SET @SQLSelect =  ' INSERT INTO Temp_Comp(col_desc, ' + REPLACE(@ColumnDeclaration, 'NVARCHAR(255)', '')  + ')' + 
                  ' SELECT col,'+ REPLACE(@ColumnDeclaration, 'NVARCHAR(255)', '')  +' FROM (' + 
  ' SELECT name, sub.* FROM sys.databases' + 
  ' OUTER APPLY (SELECT ''database_id'', CAST(database_id AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) UNION ALL SELECT ''compatibility_level'', CAST(compatibility_level AS NVARCHAR(MAX))  ) sub(col, val)) src' + 
  ' PIVOT (MAX(val) FOR name IN ('+ REPLACE(@ColumnDeclaration, 'NVARCHAR(255)', '')  +') ) piv';

SELECT @SQLSelect;
EXEC (@SQLSelect);
```

**[DBFiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=d5273f9dcb86402641a699696de090f0)**

Result:

[image]

In order to `INSERT` you could use dynamic PIVOT. To add more values just extend `OUTER APPLY` part.

Keep in mind that you've defined columns as `' NVARCHAR(255)'` so you may need to convert values before insert.

Comment: lad2025 My Table Column Is Based On Number Of Database ON SERVER that you got It.Now I wan't to Insert the Data In column 1 Of Table Temp_Comp Which contain a Database Name. Now from From The Database which is same as column of Temp_comp a specific record Into It.